# Posting an API using functions - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to call a get method on url in my function. I have script running as a supervisor. i.e the function will be called automatically when needed. When the function is called, i get the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

**supervisor.py**

```
def bug_kill():
url = "www.example.com"
r = requests.get(url)

if system_status["First"] == "First":
   bug_kill()
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error message, including traceback?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh that is only error returned in my terminal

Comment: @Jeppe, i wouldn't post new question if the others were helpful :)

Comment: Well, in the link you would find _The error means you tried to do something like `None[5]`_  - from your snippet, it could seem that `system_status` might be None.

Comment: Where have you defined system_status? What is that variable used for?

Comment: @Jeppe, the error leaves when i take out the function `bug_kill()`

Comment: Can you show us? Where is `system_status` defined and does your error-message not contain information about which line threw the error?